# How to delete object properties based on another interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

how can I to automatically `delete family` property? or at least I want to get an error tells class A is not compatible with B.

```
class A {
    name? : string; family : string = "bye";
}

class B {
    name? : string;
}

let b : B = new A();
b.name ="hiii";
//b.family = "something" <--- error, which is intended, but the variable still exist... 
console.log({...b})
```

output:

```
{
  "family": "bye",
  "name": "hiii"
}
```

my goal:

```
{
  "name": "hiii"
}
```

I'm using the spread operator to INSERT items into an sql table, and I want to make sure I have only the defined properties. I can manually map them, but is there no out-of-the-box solution?

thanks for any help attempt.

Note: Utility Types such as Pick and Required will not help since the question here is not about types

Comment: Yes, you'll need to manually map them. Add a method `toBtableRow()` to your class - `A` will either fail to implement it, or can implement it properly by returning an object that only includes the `name`.

Answer (score 0):

If we infer class A and B, we will have the following types

```
type A = {
    name? : string | undefined; 
    family : string;
};

type B = {
    name? : string | undefined;
};
```

type A is actually compatible with type B since it contains all the properties of type B and therefore is a superset of type B.

Casting the variable b (which was original of type A) to be of type B does not affect the object(variable b); that is, it does not automatically remove the properties that are not in type B. Typescript basically adds static typing for better developer experience. It is similar to the way typing to Python 3.5 for better experience and to minimize TypeError issues especially when working on large or complex codebase.

Thus, casting variable b from type A (class A) to type B (class B) on the TypeScript level will not affect the attributes/properties that was assigned to b.

I would have suggested a generic `cast` function like so:

```
function cast<T extends object>(a: T, b: T) {
  Object.keys(b).forEach((keyOfB) => {
    b[keyOfB] = a[keyOfB]
  });

  return b;
}
```

which could have done the casting on the JavaScript level

```
const a = new A();
a.name = 'Name of A';

const b = cast(a, new B());
```

But a major issue here is that instances of class A and B do not have the property `name` when initially instantiated unlike the property family in A since they do not have the property defined upon instantiation:

```
const a = new A();
const b = new B();

console.log(Object.keys(a)); // Output: ['family']
console.log(Object.keys(b)); // Output: []

a.name = 'Name of A';
b.name = 'Name of B';

console.log(Object.keys(a)); // Output: ['family', 'name']
console.log(Object.keys(b)); // Output: ['name']
```

If we want to use the function, we will have need to initialize all the properties for the two arguments to be passed which is not usually ideal.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

The only solution I can come up with is to create a function that will manually (I mean that is not generic) extract the properties of `class B` from `class A`.

```
function castToB<T extends B>(superTypeOfB: T) {
  const allPropertyKeysOfB = ['name'];

  allPropertyKeysOfB.forEach((keyOfB) => {
    b[keyOfB] = superTypeOfB[keyOfB];
  });

  return b;
}

let a : A = new A();

a.family = 'Family of A';
a.name = 'Name of A';

console.log(castToB({...a})); // Output: { name: 'Name of A' }
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that if we change the properties in class B we will need to check this as well.

Hope this helps